# Cannot pass parameter (in array) when loading javascript

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts, yii2, parameter-passing

So I have this javascript file (highchart). I want to reuse it in my view files in yii2, with different parameters.
I had no problem doing that until I had to do it with an array containing numbers:

```
<script 
    type="text/javascript" 
    iddiv="miskinprov"
    axisjudul="Persentase Penduduk Miskin"
    seriesjudul="Penduduk Miskin"
    d1=17.10
    d2=18.34
    d3=17.48
    d4=17.88
    d5=17.32
    dtextjudul="Perkembangan Persentase Penduduk Miskin <br/>di Provinsi Bengkulu, 2010-2016 (Maret)"
    dtextsubjudul='Sumber: <a href="http://bengkulu.bps.go.id/">BPS Provinsi Bengkulu</a>'
src="<?php echo Yii::$app->request->baseUrl; ?>/filejs/chartdata/1700_bkl_trend.js"></script>
```

This is the 1700_bkl_trend.js file:

```
var jscript = $('script[src*=1700_bkl_trend]');
$(function () {
Highcharts.chart(jscript.attr('iddiv'), {
    chart: {
        type: 'line',
        height: 500,
        ...
    },
    title: {
        text: jscript.attr('dtextjudul'),
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: jscript.attr('dtextsubjudul'),
    },        
    xAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Tahun',
        },
        categories: ['2012', '2013', '2014', '2015', '2016'],
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: jscript.attr('axisjudul'),
        },            
    },        
    series: [{
            name: jscript.attr('seriesjudul'),
            data: [jscript.attr('d1'), jscript.attr('d2'), jscript.attr('d3'), jscript.attr('d4'), jscript.attr('d5')],
            color: '#B22D12',
        }]
});
```

});

The problem is with this part:

```
data: [jscript.attr('d1'), jscript.attr('d2'), jscript.attr('d3'), jscript.attr('d4'), jscript.attr('d5')],
                //data: [jscript.attr('d1')],
```

The highchart shows up but the series doesn't.
I have tried using this:

```
<?php
$s1 = 17.10;
?>
d1='<?php echo json_encode($s1); ?>'
```

Also using double and single quotes in the parameters, but still no luck.
What have I not done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably lack of parseInt - HTML attributes are passed as strings, not numbers. I got it working this way (using vanillaJS)

```js
var jscript = document.querySelector('script[src*="1700_bkl_trend"]');
//var x =  [jscript.getAttribute('d1'), jscript.getAttribute('d2'), jscript.getAttribute('d3'), jscript.getAttribute('d4'), jscript.getAttribute('d5')]
//console.log(x);
(function () {
Highcharts.chart(jscript.getAttribute('iddiv'), {
    chart: {
        type: 'line',
        height: 500,
    },
    title: {
        text: jscript.getAttribute('dtextjudul'),
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: jscript.getAttribute('dtextsubjudul'),
    },        
    xAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Tahun',
        },
        categories: ['2012', '2013', '2014', '2015', '2016'],
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: jscript.getAttribute('axisjudul'),
        },            
    },        
    series: [{
            name: jscript.getAttribute('seriesjudul'),
            data: [parseInt(jscript.getAttribute('d1')), parseInt(jscript.getAttribute('d2')), parseInt(jscript.getAttribute('d3')), parseInt(jscript.getAttribute('d4')), parseInt(jscript.getAttribute('d5'))],
            color: '#B22D12',
        }]
});
})()
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script 
    type="text/javascript" 
    iddiv="miskinprov"
    axisjudul="Persentase Penduduk Miskin"
    seriesjudul="Penduduk Miskin"
    d1=17.10
    d2=18.34
    d3=17.48
    d4=17.88
    d5=17.32
    dtextjudul="Perkembangan Persentase Penduduk Miskin <br/>di Provinsi Bengkulu, 2010-2016 (Maret)"
    dtextsubjudul='Sumber: <a href="http://bengkulu.bps.go.id/">BPS Provinsi Bengkulu</a>'
src="<?php echo Yii::$app->request->baseUrl; ?>/filejs/chartdata/1700_bkl_trend.js"></script>
<div id="miskinprov"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, only I needed parseFloat instead. But thank you :)